# popviewcontroller for previous two pages

Tags: iphone

Popviewcontroller in navigationcontroller pops out just current page and sends us to previous page. Is there a way to pop out two pages and go back to page prior to previous one(2 pages back) or i have to push it to that page.
thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this method on UINavigationController:

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Like this:

```
NSInteger currentIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
if( currentIndex-2 >= 0 ) {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex-2] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: nice indexOfObject:self and safe